# How to make a flutter widget stick to the top once it reaches top in the scroll view

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a page where I have a scroll view. Inside that scroll view I'm having a navigation bar and below that navigation bar, the content goes according to the navigation bar.

So what I want is to when that navigation bar reaches the top of the page in the scroll view, it simply sticks to the top of the page and only the below content scrolls after that. How may I achieve this?

I have no code or anything to share because I'm not sure how to tackle this.

Comment: This package might help https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers